# Specifying various fonts with various scales with fontspec

Tags: fontspec

The `fontspec` package allows us to define something like:

```
\setmainfont{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}[
    BoldFont = texgyrepagella-bold.otf ,
    ItalicFont = texgyrepagella-italic.otf ,
    BoldItalicFont = texgyrepagella-bolditalic.otf ]
```

It also has a `scale` option.

I want to combine the two, and say something like: The main font is `X.otf` with scale 1, and if the main font is bold, use font `Y.otf` with scale 0.8:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% Font definition goes here...

\begin{document}
This is a simple text. It must be typeset with `X.otf`.
\textbf{This is a bold text. It must be typeset with `Y.otf`.}
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve this?

Note that this scaling should only be applied when the main font is in bold, not for all bold fonts in the text.

Comment: What do you mean by "the main font is bold”? Boldness is not an attribute of the main font. Do you mean that you want to use font Y when `\textbf` or `\bfseries` is used?

Comment: @egreg: Assume that `\textbf` or `\bfseries` is used, and the current text font is the main font (`X.otf`). What I want is that the bold text be typeset with `Y.otf` with scale 0.8.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose the two fonts "X" and "Y" are `TeX Gyre Pagella` and `TeX Gyre Heros` (Palatino and Helvetica clones, respectively). Both fonts feature normal, bold, italic, and bold-italic shapes/weights. To restrict the `Scale=0.8` option to just the bold weight of `TeX Gyre Heros`, you could issue the commands

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}  %% font "X" 
\setsansfont[BoldFeatures={Scale=0.8}]{TeX Gyre Heros}  % font "Y"
```

That way, the normal-weight, italic shape, and bold-italic shape of `TeX Gyre Heros` will *not* be scaled. Any other font families you may be loading will also not see their bold-weight font scaled.

---

*Addendum*, prompted by the OP's follow-up comment: To have one font, say "Pagella" be the main (i.e., normal-weight&normal-shape) font and, say, "Heros" be the font that's used in `\textbf{...}` and `{\bfseries ...}`, and to have bold Heros scaled by a factor of 0.8, you should enter the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFeatures={Scale=0.8}, 
             BoldFont = {TeX Gyre Heros Bold}]
            {TeX Gyre Pagella}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. I'm afraid it does not answer my question. I want this: When `\textbf` is used in some part of the text which is typeset with font "X", it changes to font "Y" with scale 0.8. Please let me know if I'm not clear.

Comment: @SadeqDousti - I'm not sure I understand your objective. Do you maybe mean something like `\setmainfont[BoldFeatures={Scale=0.8}, BoldFont = {TeX Gyre Heros Bold}]{TeX Gyre Pagella}`? This will use a scaled version of Heros for bold material, and Pagella for everything else. Please advise.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That was exactly what I wanted :D